# Java Game - Enemies AI

Tags: java

I am doing my first game in java using libgdx. It's a shooter game, and I have a problem with my enemies AI: I can't make them move or shoot bullets, they just spawn in random positions and stay there. This is what I have in my `Enemy` class:

```
import java.util.Random;

import View.World;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Enemy {

private static final Random r = new Random();
    float ROTATION_SPEED = 500;
    int x = r.nextInt(36); //top x
    int y = r.nextInt(24); //top y
    Vector2 vect = new Vector2(x,y);




    public Follower(float SPEED, float rotation, float width, float height,
                    Vector2 position) {
            super(SPEED, rotation, width, height, position);
    }

    public void move (Vector2 position){
        getPosition().x =+ 5;
        getPosition().y =+ 5;
    }
    @Override
    public void advance(float delta, Esfera ship) {

      position.lerp(vect, delta);

        rotation += delta * ROTATION_SPEED;

        if(rotation > 360)
                rotation -= 360;

        super.update(ship);
       if(vect.equals(this.getPosition())){
            x = r.nextInt(36);
            y = r.nextInt(24);

       }
```

}

And in my World Class i got this to spawn enemies:

```
public class World {

//More variable declarations

Iterator<Follower> eIter;
int Timer = 0;
int counter;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;

public float randFloat(float Min, float Max) {
    return Min + (float)(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1));
}
public void update(){
    Timer++;
    if(counter < 40){
        if(Timer % 100 == 0){
            float x = randFloat(0, 50.0f);
            float y = randFloat(0, 50.0f);
            enemies.add(new Follower(5f, 0, 1, 1, new Vector2(x, y)));

            counter++;
        }
    }
```

}

What should I implement to at least move my enemies constantly?

Comment: I think you need to make a bit more of an effort to understand the problems you are trying to solve and the code you've already got. Ask small, specific questions about the technical problems you are having. At the moment you've asked a series of questions which amount to "please write my game for me", and you're unlikely to get a lot of answers doing that.

Comment: The "I've got this, now let's bash it do this" mentality is spirited but problematic. One line, or method, or object in a program should do one thing. Correctly, and if the design was sound, without needing change.